# JavaScript src with empty tag works, with empty end doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don't self-closing script tags work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

I am using Spring web-mvc with Freemarker and JQuery. The following works fine (layout, positioning etc):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<@spring.url 'jquery.ui.core.js'/>"></script>
```

But this doesn't:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<@spring.url 'jquery.ui.core.js'/>"/>
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong, script tags just require the closing tags, they can't be self closed.

More discussion about it available on this thread:
[Why don't self-closing script tags work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

Answer (score 1):

You can't close a script tag using '/>' you have to use the explicit '</script>' closing tag.

Comment: Here's the DTD on ipr101's answer http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#edef-SCRIPT